# I want to know which Elliptical Curve used in SGX's function like sgx_ecc256_compute_shared_dhkey()?

Tags: openssl, sgx

I tried to use openssl to exchange a key with SGX by ecc, but I don't know which Elliptical Curve is used in SGX, so I can't set the parameters for openssl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 256-bit GF(p).

But, to use the Keys in OpenSSL you need to transform the Key to Little-Endian.

**Sources:**

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/709148

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-software-guard-extensions-intel-sgx/topic/740704